# Compare 2 lists in Excel ?

Tags: excel, list-comparison

I have 2 columns in a spreadsheet.  One column has around 26 extra rows than the other.  I've been trying various formulas to highlight or somehow indicate which columns are missing from the smaller of the lists...

I tried filling a 3rd colum with this :

```
=FIND(B1,A1:A1102)
```

which I though returned 1 if b1 was in the list a1:a1102 alas it doesn't seem to be true.

Anybody got any solutions for comparing 2 lists and isolating differences?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use MATCH, go with something like the following:

```
 =IFERROR(MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$1102,0),0)
```

entered into cell C1 and copied down to the end of the data in column B

This assumes that column B contains the longer list and A the shorter, of course.

The MATCH formula will return the row in which B1 is matched in A.

Comment: Returns 1 on some 2 on others, I chcked one of the 2s and one of the 1s and both are in both lists :/

Comment: Sorry, didn't make clear - the *zeroes* are the no-matches, i.e., where the B value is not in A.

Comment: Mark, you can also change the no-match 0 (the last 0 in the formula) to something more visible like "NOT THERE!"

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of  `if`, `iferror` and `vlookup` functions.

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,$A$1:$A$10,1,FALSE),"missing")="missing", 1, 0)
```

This will find matches in column A for the values in column B. If the value is missing, the `iferror` will report it missing (#N/A). Then the `if` function will output a 1 for the missing values and a 0 for those found.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:**

My bad, I suggested the wrong function - except the absolute reference, you need to use `MATCH` - as suggested in other answers: `=MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$1102,0)` or look up the whole column: `=MATCH(B1,A:A,0)`.

Missing items will be returned as `#N/A`, but it easily handled with `IFERROR`.

Comment: Cheers, my bad I did actually include =FIND(B1,$A$1:$A$1102) for the other columns, just didn't put it my example

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but I could not get MATCH() to work across different tabs in the same workbook.  Also, I'd rather not add columns if I don't have to.  What worked for me, was to use conditional formatting:

1. Select one column that you want to test (assume it's 'Z' for this example)
2. Select Conditional Formatting -> New Rule
3. Select 'Use a formula ...'
4. Use `=COUNTIF('otherTab'!$A:$A, $Z1)` - where `'otherTab'` is the name of the other tab, `'A'` is the column in that tab you want to test against and `'Z'` is the column in THIS tab
5. Set the color scheme that something that says "I found a match!" to you
6. Click OK

Then you can do the same on the other column if you need to check both.

Comment: this did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `MATCH` instead of `FIND`

Or if you want to be fancier about it, check out this thread:

https://superuser.com/questions/289650/how-to-compare-two-columns-and-find-differences-in-excel